# Calling different activities from listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, onclick

I'm trying to call different activities depending on the item the user clicks on my listview but for some reason only the first element is working.
here is the code for the listview:

```
options = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstOptions);
ArrayAdapter<String> OPTADAP= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.optionslayout,OPTIONS);
options.setAdapter(OPTADAP);

options.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
  Intent i;
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,int pos, long id) {
    switch(pos){
    case 0:
      i = new Intent(view.getContext(),Posting.class);
      i.putExtra("usrid", usrdata.get("id"));
      i.putExtra("usrname", usrdata.get("name"));
      try{
        startActivity(i);
      } catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      break;
    case 1:
      i = new Intent(view.getContext(),WallActivity.class);
      try{
        startActivity(i);
      }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      break;
    default:
      Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "default", 10).show();
    }                   
  }
}
```

for some reason the block of code in case 1 does not run, i tried putting the code from case 0 in case 1 and it worked, so it has to be something wrong with this block:

```
i = new Intent(view.getContext(),WallActivity.class);
try{
    startActivity(i);
}catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the WallActivity is basically just a webview:

```
public class WallActivity extends Activity{

WebView wv;
private final String wurl = "URL HERE";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wallactivity);
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl(wurl);
    }
}
```

When i click on item 1 the code does not run, any ideas? all the help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "for some reason the block of code in case 1" Did you try using the Eclipse debugger or adding logging code to find out what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why on earth are you catching the ActivityNotFoundException?  If i had to hazard a guess, it woud be that you forgot to register WallActivity in your manifest and that exception is being thrown.

In any case, if you do catch an exception, in Android, if you want to see the stack trace you should write the exception to the Log instead of `e.printStackTrace()`

```
Log.e(getClass().getName(), "OMG ERROR ! :)", e);
```

Comment: WOW, i feel embraced by a feeling of shame, just like you said i forgot to register my activity in my manifest file, thank you so much!!! if i'm not mistaken there used to be an error message if i didn't surround the startActivity with the try and catch, but now is gone.. hmm weird.

Comment: Right... the error message was telling you that you forgot to register your activity in the manifest :) Android never throws exceptions just for fun, so make sure you're really sure you can ignore whatever error its trying to tell you about.

Comment: @Slacker616 An error message should be the first sign that something in your code is not right. By squelching the error, you are applying a covering up a flesh wound with a towel. It won't stop the gangrene from setting in.